# Probability Of Finding One Set Of Socks

Tags: probability

> 4 sets of socks were sent to clean, 4 individual sock were randomly lost.
>   
>   What is the probability that a set of socks came back? and what it $EX$

if $X=0$ we need to choose 1 sock out of each pairs:

$P(X=0)={{2\choose 1}*{2\choose 1}*{2\choose 1}*{2\choose 1}\over {8 \choose 4}}=\frac{16}{70}$

if $X=1$ we need to choose 1 pair than 2 out of the left 3 pairs and in each to choose 1 sock out of each left 2 pairs:

$P(X=1)={{4\choose 1}*{3\choose 2}*{2\choose 1}*{2\choose 1}\over {8 \choose 4}}=\frac{48}{70}$

if $X=2$ we need to choose 2 pairs out of the 4 pairs :

$P(X=2)={{4\choose 2}\over {8 \choose 4}}=\frac{6}{70}$

$EX=0*\frac{16}{70}+1*\frac{48}{70}+2*\frac{6}{70}=\frac{6}{7}$

> Let there be $X_i$ be a dummy variable indicate the event $A_i$- the i-th pair returned from the cleaning

$EX_i=P(A_i)=\frac{6 \choose 4}{8\choose 4}=\frac{3}{14} $ So $EX=4*\frac{3}{14}=\frac{6}{7}$

Why is $P(A_i)=\frac{6 \choose 4}{8\choose 4}$? in particular why ${6 \choose 4}$?

Comment: Note that $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$ and so $\binom{6}{4}=\binom{6}{2}$.  It is easier for me to think of it as $\binom{6}{2}$ instead.  You already know that the $i^{th}$ pair came back, so those are two of your socks that you get.  There are still two more socks to choose out of the six remaining.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, looking to understand how intuitively can you think on $ 6\choose 4$